# ng-transclude not working properly on IE9 for the case of select/option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to angularjs and creating my custom select directive using ng-transclude for select/option(static data through option tag).
Here is my plunker: http://plunker.co/edit/qozbIdRZGYucW95TEqsH?p=preview
In firefox, chrome and IE10 its working as expected and I'm able to see select option data.
But on IE9 select option data is not getting populated. I analyzed angular.js code and found that addOption from optionDirective is not getting called on IE9 due to which option is not getting added on selectDirective.

Any one facing same issue on IE9 or is there any issue with my implementation?

Thanks,
Vinay

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I am seeing the same problem.